# pytorchのcuda10.0がインストールできない。公式サイト指定のコマンドで実行してもcuda9.0用がはいる

Tags: python, python3, pytorch

私の環境は
ubuntu18.04
cuda 10.0
です。

そこで、pytorch公式サイトでインストールを試みたところ

```
pip3 install https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu100/torch-1.1.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

でうまく入りませんでした。
torchvisonはcuda10.0のものが入りました。
ご教示のほどよろしくおねがいします。

```
pip3 install https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu100/torch-1.1.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
Collecting torch==1.1.0 from https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu100/torch-1.1.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
Using cached https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu100/torch-1.1.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
Collecting numpy (from torch==1.1.0)
Using cachedhttps://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/87/2d/e4656149cbadd3a8a0369fcd1a9c7d61cc7b87b3903b85389c70c989a696/numpy-1.16.4-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Installing collected packages: numpy, torch
Successfully installed numpy-1.16.4 torch-1.1.0
```

のようになりました。

Comment: 「うまく入りませんでした」と判断した理由や根拠がわかりません。追記してください。

Comment: 「torchvisonはcuda10.0のものが入りました」の部分も、何をして何を確認してそう判断したのかを追記してほしいです。

Comment: torchにかんしてはcuda9.0のパッケージが入りました。torchvisionはチュートリアルを実行した際にtorchはcuda9.0に対応しているが、torchvisionは10.0に対応しているというエラーが出ました。

Comment: あなたがやったこと（実行したコマンド）がわからない。その結果が正確にわからない。「torchvisionは10.0に対応しているというエラーが出ました」はあなたの判断でしかなく、どんなエラーだったのかはこちらにはわからない。

Comment: 「torchvisonはcuda10.0のものが入りました」の判断理由がまだわかってない。torchvisonをどう入れたのか書いてない。pip3 install https：//download.pytorch.org/whl/cu100/torch-1.1.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
 と pip3 install https：//download.pytorch.org/whl/cu100/torchvision-0.3.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
 でインストールしたはずですが……。 （リンクにされないようにコロンを全角にしました）
あと、情報はコメントではなくて質問を修正しましょう。

Comment: シンプルに質問にtorchvisonをどうやってインストールしたのかが書いてないんですね。それを最初に指摘すればよかったのですね。すみませんでした。